# Inheritance in camel routes

Tags: apache, inheritance, routes, apache-camel

I have a set of microservices and I want to have a common camel route end point to serve the request

Same my microservices are
1. Student
2. Teacher
3. HouseKeeping

All these microservices have common CRUD methods and their own custom methods.

Is it possible to design something like

```
class MasterRoute extends RouteBuilder{
  //Route for All CRUD methods
}

class Student extends RouteBuilder{
  //Inherited common routes
  from ( "overridden get route from the Master Route").log( "does it make sense?? ");

  from("a custom route specific to student").log( "does it make sense?? ")
}
```

Comment: Why not have separate routes for your services but in the routes refer to the common CRUD methods?

Comment: Yes its just Java code, so you can use Java inheritance and override the configure method, and call super.configure etc. And have getter/setter to configure each RouteBuilder instances. However simetimes inheritance is overrated in Java and you may have more trouble doing so than just a bit of copy/paste code.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti All have common "CRUD OPERATION". not the same method. means. All microservices have create , update, read, delete. So i want to make a generic route.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Yes . ofcourse its java code. But I want to know the how much does it make sense in case of a camel route

Comment: Ok but generic routes are usually harder to manage as you had more complexity. Introducing change is alsot a bit harder as it can introduce unexpected results. Keep the route setup simple but in your routes e.g. in your processor classes you then work with inherited crud methods.